# Why does JS keep insertion order in Set?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, set

Randomly experimenting with JavaScript (ES6) and reading its documentation I found out that `Set` maintains the insertion order of its elements.

I wonder what is the rationale behind this decision? I always thought of a set as an unordered collection. Requiring anything more would lead to a more costly implementation, whereas, in my opinion, this feature is mostly unused.

Comment: Because the API says it's iterable in insertion order, see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set.

Comment: Your question is not really a question.  That specific implementation on that specific data may keep order.  But Set does not guarantee order.  So the bottom line is, do not use a set if you care about order.

Comment: @nycynik A set does guarantee order...insertion order

Comment: @nycynik the ES2015 spec explicitly mandates that insertion order be used for iteration over set contents. I wouldn't write code to exploit that of course.

Comment: *Ordered* sets can be useful. If you want to know why though, I'd recommend to search through the meeting notes of the TC39 committee and/or reach out to them directly.

Comment: I don't get you all. This is a valid question.

Comment: @felixKling probably the later, the [notes](https://github.com/tc39/tc39-notes/tree/master/es6) aren't complete

Comment: It’s useful occasionally, not easy to implement on top of `Set`, and probably doesn’t have to come with that much overhead. When Python moved to ordered dicts, they got faster =)

Comment: @jonrsharpe – as others noted – my question is not "why JS code runs this way", but "why JS was **designed** to run this way".

Comment: @FelixKling – thank you for the note about TC39. However, I can hardly find anything about "insertion order" in available TC39 notes.
I'm looking for any reason for such spec. Maybe it was already obvious at the time EC2015 was created and required no discussion, or it's some kind of legacy assumptions?

Comment: @Axs: BTW, don't mind downvotes and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 39):

Ordered Sets are very useful, consider for example:

```
unique_elements_in_order = [...new Set(some_array)]
```

In an "unsorted set" language, like python, you'd need a separate `OrderedSet` implementation for this to work.

Yes, theoretically, sets are not ordered, but mathematical abstractions, like sets, functions, numbers etc, are only tangentially related to similarly named objects we use in programming. `Set` is just a special kind of data structure, and it's up to the language designers to define its specific properties, like "Sets are in the insertion order" or "Sets can only contain hashable objects" etc.

As to the committee's motivation, some googling brought [this](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2012-February/020525.html)

> Mark S. Miller:

> Mon Feb 13 22:31:28 PST 2012

> There are many benefits to determinism. E started with non-deterministic
> iteration order, which opens a covert channel hazard. I initially changed
> to deterministic order merely to plug this leak. Having done so, I found it
> had many software engineering benefits. For example, it becomes much easier
> to write regression tests and to reproduce bugs by re-execution. In my
> implementation, it also had a minor additional space and time cost. Tyler's
> Waterken tables show that even the minor runtime costs I was paying were
> unnecessary.

> Let's not introduce yet another source of non-determinism for the sake of
> an unmeasured efficiency. Let's measure, and if the cost turns out to be
> high after all, then let's reconsider determinism.

Comment: Too bad that Python sets don't keep insertion order. There are [third party packages](https://pypi.org/project/ordered-set/) for this but that means that I do not have the nice set syntax at hand.

Comment: Interesting that golang has the completely opposite philosophy

Comment: it's not that simple. Ordered Sets and Sets would need different Equality test implementation. Eg. in python {3,4} == {4,3} which is super useful and logical. JS has no real equality typeclass (trait, interface whatever) so you have to implement the check yourself anyways.