# how can i ensure there is no content that appears more than once after the '/'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string which displays a path. The issue is sometimes the path contains the same text more than once after the '/' as shown below. I want to ensure that if that happens, the content is removed. How can I solve this?

```js
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
     const trimEnd = str => str.endsWith('/') ? str.slice(0, -1) :
                            str;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="FilePath" id="FilePath" value="/content/enforced/12063-CC-125/12063-CC-125/">
```

Comment: What's the comment for?

Comment: Use a regular expression with a back-reference to detect duplicate substrings.

Comment: So `/content/enforced/12063-CC-125/12063-CC-125/` becomes `/content/enforced/12063-CC-125/`?

Comment: yes it becomes that

Comment: @Barmar, I think splitting the string into an array and then using a `Set` to remove duplicate values would work in this case, I was going to answer when you closed it :)

Comment: @YaakovAinspan Someone else managed to post an answer anyway.

Comment: @Barmar lol, I guess they got in quick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split by `/`, get unique values with [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and join:

```js
const str = "/content/enforced/12063-CC-125/12063-CC-125/";
const res = [...new Set(str.split("/"))].join('/');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Is `Set` guaranteed to maintain the original ordering?

Comment: @Barmar Apparently [it does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55460303/why-does-js-keep-insertion-order-in-set)

Comment: I aslso assumed from the example that they only care about duplicates that are adjacent, but maybe that's not a concern.