# Merge and remove duplicates from multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, typescript

My function takes an array of arrays and returns the merged array without duplicates

```
function mergeArrayOfPrimitives<T>(
  primitiveArraysTobeMerged: Array<Array<T>>
): Array<T> {
  const merged: Array<T> = [];
  primitiveArraysTobeMerged.forEach((primitiveArray: Array<T>) =>
    [...merged].concat([...primitiveArray])
  );
  return [...new Set([...merged])];
}
```

But when I test it on `typescript` playground with below inputs, it returns `[]` instead of `['CORE - AGILE']`

```
console.log(mergeArrayOfPrimitives([[], ['CORE - AGILE']])); ==> [LOG]: []
```

Comment: concat returns new array. you are not doing anything to merged here basically. perhaps you could try `merged.push(...primitiveArray)`

Comment: @cmgchess [...merged, ...primitiveArray] also returns same result

Comment: @cmgchess Is there a way to do it immutably? push will alter the original array

Comment: original array here means?

Comment: the merged array

Comment: how about a `let merged = []` and  then reassign `merged =[...merged].concat...`

Comment: `concat` returns a new array, you're not doing anything with the result.

Comment: You only need one temporary object - the deduplication set. You can add all elems one by one - they will be iterated in inserion order. See: https://tsplay.dev/w22L4w

Comment: Thank you @Lesiak 
Please add it to the answer I will accept this.

Comment: You aren't assigning the result of your concat to anything. Also there is no reason not to mutate `merged`, it's just a waste to repeatedly make copies of your arrays. You can just call a single concat `return [...new Set([].concat(...primitiveArraysTobeMerged))];` here using spread syntax to spread the passed 2d array, not to create a copy of it.

Comment: Thanks @pilchard
I think the simplest solution will be return [...new Set(...primitiveArraysTobeMerged)];

Comment: @izengod that isn't what I said and that won't achieve your goal. A set operating on arrays will not dedupe them. You'll note my comment includes a `concat` call on the spread arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution fails as you ignore the result of concat: The concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.

On top of that, your solution seems to create a lot of temporary arrays - none of which is necessary.

You only need one temporary object - the deduplication set. You can add all elems one by one - they will be iterated in insertion order. See [Why does JS keep insertion order in Set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55460303/why-does-js-keep-insertion-order-in-set)

Set API is minimalistic - you need a foreach loop to add all elements form an array. See [How to add an array of values to a Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50881453/how-to-add-an-array-of-values-to-a-set)

```ts
function mergeArrayOfPrimitives<T>(
  primitiveArraysTobeMerged: Array<Array<T>>
): Array<T> {
  const dedupSet = new Set<T>();
  primitiveArraysTobeMerged.forEach(a => a.forEach(dedupSet.add, dedupSet));
  return [...dedupSet];
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwKYCcDmqCC70CGAngPLAAK6MyMsAbqgM4A8AKgHwAUAUIogA5Ua9XPmKNWcAEaoAshmwATAFyI8hIs3XE27dtwCUq7Zo6IA3r0QQEjKIkWpFIfgGVU9gLyIwqAO6I7lC6nAYA3FaC1LQwDCYS0nIKTgB0wHDoAKIEEAAWnASInuyIBGkZ2Xmcjs5uHikEiooANA5OLkEG4VboHiDoSADaKSM1HR4AuhEAvtzcNmCMcAA2qCnLcJicaFiiGmSU0SKMnIODAIzNAEzNACzNAGwTrRePzQCsExNdEQtLq%20tNttkiYDkIYgwTmdnohBgByADCJAASplEABaNQAcQAkgAZTJwr4-IA)